# mapnik xml and carto css

Tags: carto, software-recommendations, mapnik, xml

I have a large mapnik xml file that I would like to convert to carto css to manage with tile-mill. What tools should I use on Ubuntu 14.04. I have tried to compile the cartogenerator from Dane but it fails to compile with errors. What other tools are available to convert this. I have also tried the mapcss-tools but it also fails with error.

Comment: How big is big? What errors do you get?

Comment: check issues in https://github.com/rundel/carto-generator

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no converter from Mapnik XML to CartoCSS. Only the other way around. Cascading proper is hard.

Comment: try using the https://github.com/rundel/carto-generator